# How to deactivate media-scanner

Tags: usb, autostart, media

I observed that when I plug a USB hard drive, Ubuntu starts a service called `mediascanner-extractor` and `mediascanner-service-2.0`. What is this? It looks like its kind of new, because I didn't noticed this before (I'm using *Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS*)

How to avoid this? because it hits the perfs of my PC. Does anyone knows how?

I searched the site but found no relevant info about it.

Comment: Curious to what keyword you used :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm oupsy, I guess I started with media-scanner... lousy me.

Comment: Don't worry, if the linked answer solves the issue (it did in my case) you can close it as a dupe.

Comment: Yes I can add `.nomedia` at the root of my usb drive